# Location of New Window after old window closed

Tags: cocoa, macos, nswindow

I have an app that allows multiple windows.  I have a strange bug where, if I repeatedly open and close windows, new windows are positioned lower and lower on the screen.  I would expect this if I were keeping the windows open, but it seems that the OS X window tiling mechanism is unaware of when my windows are closing.

Potentially relevant notes:  I am using garbage collection.  This is not a document-based app.  When I close a window, the corresponding menu item is removed from the "Window" menu.

Any hints as to what I might be doing wrong would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I remember running into this in my own application a while ago. As far as I could tell, this is just the way that Apple does things. I tried the same thing in other apps, and it was the same story.

Apple's [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/WinPanel/Tasks/SizingPlacingWindows.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000228-BCICDDAI) indicates that windows will cascade by default, but you can use the [`cascadeTopLeftFromPoint:`](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindow/cascadeTopLeftFromPoint:) method if you want to change the default behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the window to retain its position when re-opened, set a value for the window's `Autosave` field in Interface Builder.

You can also set this programmatically using `-setFrameAutosaveName:`.